# Testing for regexp match not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a HTML form, and I wrote a JavaScript/jQuery script which tests if the field matches a regexp. However, what happens is that the regexp tester does not work and matches any string I input. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
<span id="namecheck"></span>
```

**JS**

```
$("#name").keyup(function () {
    if (/^[A-Za-z \-]{0,35}/.test($(this).val())) {
        $("#namecheck").html("<i style=\"color:green\">Match!</i>");
    } else {
        $("#namecheck").html("<i style=\"color:darkred\">No match!</i>");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fLnhhgy/1/)

Since I'm kind of a newbie in JS (started learning it recently), I'm probably making some really dumb mistake but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a `$` at the end of your regular expression. A dollar sign indicates that it's the end of the string, so if you add that to your regex then it will only match strings with a length of 0 to 35:

```
/^[A-Za-z \-]{0,35}$/
```